# AngularJS - ngModel won't update in ngOptions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

So I have a select using both a `ngOptions` and a `ngModel` in my `AngularJS` application. For some reason I can't get the model to change to the selected value.

`$scope.selected` keeps its initial value

```
    $scope.options = [];
    $scope.selected;

    $scope.save = function(){
        var item = $scope.selected;

        console.info('item : ', item)

        console.info('save : ', $scope.selected,
                    '\n', $scope.options)
    };

    function setOptions(options){
        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
            var option = {
                label: options[i].tyTxt,
                value: options[i].tyID
            };
            if(i === 0){
                $scope.selected = option.value;
            }
            $scope.options.push(option);
        }
    }
```

```
<select ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in options track by $index" ng-model="selected"></select>

<span ng-click="save()">
    save
</span>
```

**EDIT**
I've even tried this:

```
    function setOptions(options){
        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
            var option = {
                label: options[i].tyTxt,
                value: options[i].tyID
            };
            if(i === 0){
                $scope.selected = option.value;
            }
            $scope.options.push(option.value);
        }
    }
```

```
<select ng-options="item for item in options" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

but with same result

Comment: Where do the `options` come from? Is `$scope.options` initialised as an array? Is `setOptions` ever called?

Comment: it comes from another `function` which gets them from the database. I didn't see the relevance of adding that part of the code, since I'm converting them into new opbjects. But if its needed I'll add the code ;-)

Comment: Be careful using `select as` and `track by` ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-

Comment: I dont see any issue in your code. Before EDIT the track by was not set up correctly. Take a look at this fiddler - http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3726/. It is working as expected and the model is changing. Maybe you can compare and check if there is any issue with your code. Can you share your entire controller code?

Comment: @PratikBhattacharya nice demo but you might want to use a slightly more modern version of Angular than 1.0.1. Here's a 1.5.5 version ~ http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3729/

Comment: @Phil thanks for that. I overlooked the version, I realize its pretty old.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angularjs then no need to use **setOptions()** in your code instead return json response from backend and initialise the array as follow.

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <select ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in options" ng-model="selected"></select>
    <p>
    <b>Selected value = </b>{{selected}}
    </p>
    <button ng-click="save()">
        save
    </button>
    </div>
```

This is the controller code

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.save = function(){
            var item = $scope.selected;

            console.info('item : ', item)

            console.info('save : ', $scope.selected,
                        '\n', $scope.options)
        };

            $scope.options = [{label:"data-1",value:1},{label:"data-2",value:2},{
        label:"data-3",value:3}];
    }
```

In the above angularjs code **$scope.options** is static declared for the sample. you just return the response into this
 [{label:"data-1",value:1},{label:"data-2",value:2},{
            label:"data-3",value:3}] and assign it to the **$scope.options**